# Appcelerator Titanium Mobile showTimePickerDialog not showing

Tags: android, appcelerator

I posted this on the Appcelerator Q&A but I've got a feeling that place is kinda dead. So...

I've seen the [bug reports](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-7880) for 1.8 regarding the showDate/TimePickerDialog's and have upgraded to 2.0.1. The date picker works fine but the time picker neither shows or erros out.

This works:

```
datepicker.showDatePickerDialog({
    value: My.date,
    callback : function(e) {
        if(!e.cancel) {

        }
    }
});
```

This does nothing:

```
timepicker.showTimePickerDialog({
    value: My.date,
    callback : function(e) {
        if(!e.cancel) {

        }
    }
});
```

With:

```
var datepicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    minDate : new Date(),
    value : My.date,
    selectionIndicator : false,
    useSpinner : true,
    height : height,
    zIndex : 5
});

var timepicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    useSpinner : true,
    selectionIndicator : true,
    type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
    height : height,
    value : My.date,
    zIndex : 5
});
```

Any ideas why date works but time doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a year late on this reply but i too faced this issue. What worked for me was to add the time picker to a view. before calling the picker dialog.

```
var timePickerView = Ti.UI.createView({...});
var pickerTime = Titanium.UI.createPicker({...});
timePickerView.add(pickerTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and I solved it by removing the value property from the `showTimePickerDialog` method, that way the Time Picker is shown on top.

This is another example of the documentation saying a property is supported for a method but in reality it is not, or as it happens in this case, causes a bug in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use local var timepicker.
I had the same problem and this trick helped me.